# Float didn't showing normally (dart languange)

Tags: oop, dart

I'm trying to calculate the number 4.2 + 0.2 - 0.1
However Despite having the value of 4.3 the output was 4.300000000000001.

This is the `animal.dart` class

```
class Animal {
  String name = '';
  int age;
  double weight = 0;

  Animal(this.name, this.age, this.weight);

  void eat() {
    print('$name is eating.');
    weight = weight + 0.2;
  }

  void sleep() {
    print('$name is sleeping.');
  }

  void poop() {
    print('$name is pooping.');
    weight = weight - 0.1;
  }
}
```

and this is the `main()` function

```
import "dart:io";
import "lorem.dart";


void main(){
var pet = Animal('Flowie', 2, 4.2);

  pet.eat();
  pet.poop();
  print(pet.weight);
}
```

and the output is the following:

```
Flowie is eating.
Flowie is pooping.
4.300000000000001
```

what's the correct way to output the weight to `4.3` instead of `4.300000000000001` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: yes thank you, I guess i'll be using normal integers instead